# Null value is still evaluated after testing it with condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have the following LINQ query:

```
houses.Where(x => 
  x.A && user.B 
  || 
  (x.Address == null || user.Address == null ? false : x.Address.CountryCode == user.Address.CountryCode
))
```

I get an error when `user.Address` is null in:

```
user.Address.CountryCode
```

To avoid that I tried to use:

```
x.Address == null || user.Address == null
```

But it seems `user.Address.CountryCode` is still evaluated.

How can I avoid that?

Comment: Your code requires that the reader remember all of the C# operator precedence rules.  Consider adding some more parentheses.  Also look up the C# `?.` and `??` operators

Comment: Using brackets changes anything? (x.Address == null || user.Address == null) ?

Comment: @Longoon12000 You cannot use ?. on a lambda expression using Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely EF Core 3.0 query translator defect.

For now (and in general) you can avoid it by not using conditional operator `?:` for criteria expressions which need to be converted to SQL query parameters (like your `user.Address.CountryCode`), but the equivalent logical binary expressions.

e.g. instead of

```
(x.Address == null || user.Address == null ? false : x.Address.CountryCode == user.Address.CountryCode)
```

use the equivalent

```
(x.Address != null && user.Address != null && x.Address.CountryCode == user.Address.CountryCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I find this logic confusing. You might try:

`( (x?.Address?.CountryCode != null && user?.Address?.CountryCode != null) ? x.Address.CountryCode == user.Address.CountryCode : false`

If that doesn't work then there is something very odd going on with the `Address` or `CountryCode` properties! Probably and entity framework issue.

Comment: You cannot use x?.Address?. on a lambda expression ... At least not with Entity Framework